# Are og:latitude and og:longitude deprecated

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I am using the following meta `og:latitude` and `og:longitude` on a website.

```html
<meta property='og:latitude' content='...' />
<meta property='og:longitude' content='...' />
```

[This forum post](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/issues/2941632) says `og:latitude` have been replaced by `place:location:latitude`
Unfortunatly, the link to the [Facebook developer documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/place/#markup) is dead.

The [Open Graph Protocol official website](https://ogp.me/) does not mention either of the syntaxes. I found [this article from Facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/06/05/platform-updates--new-open-graph-business-object-type/) mentionning it, but it is from 2013, so as the OPG website does not mention it, I am not sure if it is reliable.

My question is, where can I find an recent documentation saying:

- `og:latitude` is deprecated
- `place:location:latitude` is the current standard

Answer (score 1):

While `og:latitude` mentioned on [this](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Open_Graph_protocol) page, it is no longer existing on any official FB or OpenGraph documentation page.

There are indeed two questions:

- whether it is mentioned on any official source about usage of these properties,
- whether these properties are in fact supported.

An answer to the first question i think is `no`. The answer to the second question you can get only on empirical way: create a page with markup and validate it through [official debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).